# What is the correct way to align checkboxes using Twitter Bootstrap without taking up a whole column segment?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout, checkbox

I have a bootstrap form that generates potential invoices for each member entity (one per line). Each member's row is starts with a checkbox (without label) to identify which <kbd>Invoices</kbd> to flush to the database.

I'm new to Twig and bootstrap and I'm having a problem correctly structuring my template to present this correctly to the user. My current code (below) generates the page ok, although the `{{ form_widget(invoice.selected) }}` is taking up an entire column block. Is there I a way I can have each checkbox right-aligned some how or included as part of the column block used for the `invoice.memberid` widget?

```
{% block body %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 ">
                <div class="row">
                    <h1 class="col-sm-6"> {{ page_title }}:</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

        {{ form_start(form) }}

                 <div class="row">
                      {{ form_label(form.batchevent, 'Batch Invoice Description',{'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-12'}}) }}
                      {{ form_widget(form.batchevent, {'attr': {'class': 'col-sm-12'}}) }}
                 </div>

         {% for invoices in form %}
              {% for invoice in invoices %}
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-sm-1 checkbox">
                              <label>
                                    {{ form_widget(invoice.selected) }}
                              </label>
                         </div>

                         {{ form_widget(invoice.member_id,  {'attr': {'class': 'col-sm-2'}}) }}
                         {{ form_widget(invoice.amount,      {'attr': {'class': 'col-sm-2'}}) }}
                         {{ form_widget(invoice.invoicedate, {'attr': {'class': 'col-sm-2 datepicker'}}) }}
                         {{ form_widget(invoice.currency,    {'attr': {'class': 'col-sm-2'}}) }}
                         {{ form_widget(invoice.comments,    {'attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3'}}) }}
                    </div>
              {% endfor %}
         {% endfor %}

                 <div class="row">
                      <input type="submit" value="Generate invoices" class="btn btn-default pull-left"/>
                 </div>

        {{ form_end(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This gives the following layout (line repeated for every member):

[image]

The `form_widget()` generates HTML as below (using member_id as example):

```
<select id="invoice_batch_invoice_ids_0_member_id" name="invoice_batch[invoice_ids][0][member_id]" class="col-sm-2">            
    <option value="1" >Member 1  </option>            
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Member 2</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: What does `form_widget` render as in HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the checkbox in a column rather than applying the column class to it like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 text-left">
    {{ form_widget(invoice.selected) }}
</div>
```

This should stop it spanning the entire column.

Comment: Thanks – that nudges the checkbox up slight to be vertically aligned with the other fields (textbox column excluded) which looks better. However, it’s still floating in the middle of it’s assigned column. Is there a way to ‘right align’ it in its column so that that on desktops it doesn’t look so lonely? (see image in question)

Comment: Thanks @Gareth - I'm away from the computer now but I'll check when I'm home this evening :)

Comment: Thanks that work perfectly - although with `text-right` ;-)